# SQL fill next date (month) with loop

Tags: sql, loops, dateadd

I have input table, and need to add missing dates, but not to max, but up to next available month.
so I need to use loop.

```
SET @mindate = '2021.01'
SET @maxdate = CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) --date today as max date
while 
begin
if @mindate => @maxdate 
begin 
break
end
set @mindate = @mindate + 1
end
```

then i can get 1+.. but it does not stop to 7 month

so i  totally got stuck with writing loop.

Data table :

[image]

could anybody help on code? as most examples are with joins, to data tables, or to one max value.

Comment: `2021.01` is not a date.

Comment: You don't need a *loop* for this, relational databases *rarely* require a loop to solve problems. Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, include sample data and desired results *as text*. And as noted, `'2021.01'` is just a string, it's not any valid date.

Comment: @Stu, please, if you may, revise my solution. Is there a better way to aggregate `price_history_boundaries`? I know it won't scale and is far from production-ready, but it may help @Paul with other approaches. Give him a break :-) At least, he's willing to get rid of loops!

Comment: Oh, by the way. @Stu, I'm impressed with how much you scored in just nine months. Great contributions.

Comment: thanks for everybody. yes, my bad - '2021.01' not a date, but i use this format in BI for some month figures, avoiding date formats.  for picture - i will know that in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul, I'm assuming that you forgot to specify the month in your mock data.

I hope the code below may help you understand how non-trivial is what you are trying to accomplish :-) Kudos for your will to get rid of loops.

To make it better, I propose a denormalization (CAUTION!):

- create another column `price_valid_until`
- the latest prices records will have `price_valid_until = '21000101'` (aka, far away in the future)
- when registering a new price, update the previous with `new price_valid_from - 1 day`

Here's the solution, with a pretty complex, but efficient query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ab23/4)

```
create table price_history(
  SKU varchar(255),
  price_valid_from date,
  price decimal(16, 2)
)

insert into price_history
values
  ('a', '20210101', 10),
  ('a', '20210107', 12),
  ('b', '20210102', 4),
  ('b', '20210110', 2),
  ('b', '20210214', 5);

-- This fiddler won't let me initialize and reference:
-- 
-- declare
--   @from_date date,
--   @to_date   date;
-- 
-- select
--   @from_date = min(date_from),
--   @to_date   = max(date_from)
-- from price_history

with
  date_range as(
    select
      min(price_valid_from) as from_date,
      --
      eomonth(
        max(price_valid_from)
      ) as to_date
    from price_history
  ),
  --
  all_dates as(
    select from_date as date_in_range
    from date_range
    -- ----------
    union all
    -- ----------
    select dateadd(day, 1, date_in_range)
    from all_dates
    where
      date_in_range < (
        select to_date
        from date_range
      )
  ),
  --
  price_history_boundaries as(
    select
      ph.SKU,
      ph.price,
      --
      ph.price_valid_from,
      -- The latest price, so far, is valid until 01/01/2100
      coalesce(
        dateadd(
          day,
          -1,
          min(ph_next.price_valid_from)
        ),
        '21000101'
      ) as price_valid_until
    from
      price_history ph
        left outer join price_history ph_next
        on(
              ph_next.SKU              = ph.SKU
          and ph_next.price_valid_from > ph.price_valid_from
        )
    group by ph.SKU, ph.price_valid_from, ph.price
  )
select
  phb.SKU,
  ad.date_in_range,
  phb.price
from
  all_dates ad
    inner join price_history_boundaries phb
    on(
          phb.price_valid_from  <= ad.date_in_range
      and phb.price_valid_until >= ad.date_in_range
    )
order by phb.SKU, ad.date_in_range
```

Comment: whow ! Super big thanks !  works perfect !

Comment: So, @paul, please, don't forget to UPVOTE! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve your desired result by creating  list of dates from which to *join to*. Here I've used a recursive CTE to create a range of dates, adding 1 month per iteration up to the current date.

It's then a simple matter of joining to your source data, here `lead()` is handy for limiting the joined rows. Also, assuming *SQL Server* from the usage of *Getdate*:

```
declare @start date=(select Min([date]) from sourcetable);

with m as (
    select 1 num, @start [Date]
    union all
    select num+1 , DateAdd(month,1,m.[date])
    from m
    where DateAdd(month,1,m.[date]) <= GetDate()
), t as (
    select *, Lead([date],1,GetDate()) over (order by [date]) NextDate
    from sourcetable
)
select m.[Date], t.sku, t.price
from m
join t on m.[date] >= t.[date] and m.[date] < t.nextdate
```

See [Working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fa905229d7c4e8775fe6f458f682de6)

Comment: thanks ! this code for me looks more simple. nice , thanks a lot !  and sad that i can't mark both answers as right ..

Comment: also it shows only 1 SKU , but i will correct it , as i like this code  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d2e33b1b01802924fd6f6b7ae3ea164b  here i added another sku.

Comment: No prob - appreciate it wasn't the first answer, unfortunately family got in the way ;-). Your sample data set is not really enough to appreciate the full requirement or edge scenarios so I'm not surprised if it doesn't meet all your expectations, but all are easily implementable, you could use `lead()` on the SKU also. If it helps you out, an upvote would be nice! :)

Comment: hi Stu , sorry to disturb you, tried with lead change, but as never used lead, seems i need more time .. the main issue is that i need for both SKU a , b, and others to prolong months. so here is example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d91b9db6a381d30a37e7d85a4a019a8    , so totally query makes 12 periods, but should be  for a and b sku, now it's a mix. but with one sku only a  - works fine. how to make work with 2 sku .. ?